# Change HTML with jQuery but preserve CSS3 Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that changes the HTML of a class called `.content` which has the following animation:

```
.content{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
}
```

With the click of a button I change its HTML like so:

```
$('.button-about').click(function(){
    $('.content').html('<h1>Test</h1>');
});
```

This works fine, but the problem is that the animation isn't reloaded, the HTML is simply changed, which is what is expected. Is there any way to preserve the animation when the HTML changes?

Thanks!

EDIT: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7wU/

Comment: How you're calling the `fadein` ? Adding `HTML` does not trigger animations :)

Comment: Added a jsFiddle. Calling `fadein` just from CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roko mentioned, changing HTML of an element will not trigger animations.

However, you can achieve your desired outcome by:

1. Cloning your current element
2. Replacing the HTML of the clone with your HTML
3. Removing the existing element

> ```
> var el     = $('.content'),  
> newone = el.clone(true);
>
> newone.html('<h1>Test</h1>');
> el.before(newone);
>
> $(".content:last").remove();
> ```